# What are general tips for building recursive functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, reference

So I know what recursive functions are, but every time I have a task that seems like recursion is the way to go, I am not sure where to start.  What are some good ways to think about how to approach the problem?  For example, should I start from the last case scenario (the scenario that causes the recursion to stop) or the first case scenario?

Any references or guides that explain the approach (as opposed to what is recursion itself) would be helpful.  Or maybe it's not that hard and I'm just overthinking it.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/63318827/7060522

Comment: Requests for off-site resources are off-topic here.  With that said, any time you have a task for which recursion seems a good choice, bear in mind that recursion is almost *never* the right choice in real-world programs.

Comment: So what's on topic - is there a posting rules like subreddits? And why is that?  What is preferred?

Comment: A helpful place to look would be books on primarily functional programming programming languages, which tend to deal heavily with recursion. As an example, here's a passage on [Thinking Recursively](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion#thinking-recursively) from a canonical Haskell book. That being said, most Python implementations are ill-suited for recursive functions since function calls have a much higher performance cost than e.g. consuming an iterator.

Comment: @confused See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) from he help center. All SE sites have these pages.

Comment: Unless you are dealing with a recursive *data structure*, you will almost certainly want to use iteration instead of recursion in Python.

Comment: @JohnBollinger „recursion is almost never the right choice in the real-world“ seems like a pretty weird blanket statement. *For some* real-world usecases recursion is *never* the right choice. *For some* real-world usecases recursion is *always* the right choice. For the rest, preference and language play a key role. While many beginner problems are not recursive, too quickly rejecting recursion as a solution may become a self-fulfilling prophecy because one will reject *doing* recursion-suitable problems.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is generally about solving a problem by dividing it into subproblems, until you reach a base case (or as you said, a "last" case). Once you have the base case(s) and the general case, you have solved the recursive problem.

The general case is usually the trickier bit. For some problems it can be more obvious, but a good tactic is to start with the simplest input you can think of (which may be your base case), and then work your way up to more complicated inputs.

For example, if you want to process a non-empty array in some manner recursively, you first solve the problem for arrays of length 1, then arrays of length 2, etc. until you see the general solution.

Practice is often most helpful. Look at solutions to example problems (after attempting them yourself) until you get a better feel for it. Good luck!